# How do I get all current sessions from django?

Tags: python, django, session

I recently struggled to do this so i thought I would answer my own question to help. Found this out after playing with `dir(Session.objects)`, after importing `from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session`.

Answer (score 1):

I used this, returning a list of dictionaries containing all of the sessions' data.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
sessions = Session.objects.iterator() # also works with Session.objects.get_queryset()
for session in sessions: # iterate over sessions
    data = session.get_decoded() # decode the session data
    data["session_key"] = session.session_key # normally the data doesn't include the session key, so add it
    print(data)
```

Comment: This will only work for db-backed sessions. If you are using some other session backend (file, cookie etc) you will need a different strategy.